# How to create a facebook likebox with more then 100 faces?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a website where people can like a certain page, there are 2 things on the page.

1. A introducing text.
2. A facebook likebox.

The purpose of this site is some kind of voting website. Where people can vote on the particular facebook page.
When they have voted I want their face to display underneath the likebox. Nothing special I thought..
But it comes: When I try it out with a page who has more then 100 likes (faces) it just shows circa 100 faces, instead of the 2,9K I have on my FB page.
So what I want to know is:

1. How can I get all of the people to show?
2. How can I let the likebox automatically change height when a new row of faces is created.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Peace project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=190551424481588";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<p>Some introducing  text</p>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/dubsteptutor" data-height="3000" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I've change the data-height to 3000, but it still won't show all faces.
Check out my html file here: `http://brq.nl/fb-like/`

I really need help here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`data-height` only controls the height of the Like Box in pixels and not the number of faces to display.

I've played around with the Like Box tool of Facebook and it seems like there is a limit to display 100 faces max., regardless of what you set as the `data-height`. The parameter documentation also does not contain information about how one may be able to set the number of faces so this should be impossible at the moment.

Comment: That's exactly what I was afraid of. Damn. Thanks for the help man